# Preg_match_all -- grab all html code(data) between <table></table>

Tags: php, web-scraping, html-table

I want to grab all html between:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="list" width="100%">
.
.
.
.
</tbody>

preg_match_all('XXXXXXXXXX', $this->markup, $links);
```

Comment: Don't use regexp to parse HTML, use a DOM parsing library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, I'd recommend to use DomDocument instead of a regular expression too. But DomDocument requires some extra hussle in this case, because OP wants the HTML code, not only the nodeValue(s). (Anyway, for a DomDocument-based approach you could use some "workaround" like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#86803) (to get the table's contents incl. HTML.))

That being said, here's the regex you asked for:

```
$html = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="list" width="100%">' .
        '<tr><td>Lorem</td><td>Ipsum</td></tr>' . 
        '</table>';

preg_match_all('/<table.*?>(.*?)<\/table>/si', $html, $matches); 

var_dump($matches[1][0]); // string(37) "<tr><td>Lorem</td><td>Ipsum</td></tr>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of parsing this with regex.

Answer (score -1):

Use [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) for this operation.
PhpQuery has syntax like jQuery, and it's simply for understanding